# Why can't read this code: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException, at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source),

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, java.util.scanner, filereader

<

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Main.main(Main.java:14)>>
```

I am trying to make a file reader , it should read from textfile a 9 digit and make a ISBN Number. this gives constantly error : Exception in the thread....

the 9 digits are like this :
013601267< enter>

013031997

013292373
here is my code:

```
    File  fr = new File("ISBN.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(fr);
    int s ; int sum; int c10;
    while (in.hasNextInt()) {
        int c1 = in.nextInt();
        int c2 = in.nextInt();
        int c3 = in.nextInt();
        int c4 = in.nextInt();
        int c5 = in.nextInt();
        int c6 = in.nextInt();
        int c7 = in.nextInt();
        int c8 = in.nextInt();
        int c9 = in.nextInt();

        String set = in.next();

         sum = Integer.parseInt(set);

         c10 = (c1 * 1 + c2 * 2 + c3 * 3 + c4 * 4 + c5 * 5 + c6 * 6 + c7
                * 7 + c8 * 8 + c9 * 9) % 11;
         s = c1+c2+c3+c4+c5+c6+c7+c8+c9;

        System.out.print("" + s);

        if (c10 == 1) 
            {
            System.out.println(set);

            } 
        else if (c10 % 11 == 0) 
            {
            System.out.println(set + "X");
            }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: to add on top of Zyn's comment, the part of the error you provide (Exception in the thread...) is common to all java exception. Therefore this alone is not sufficient to understand what happened. You must provide the complete text (even if it seems long) to provide more information

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Main.main(Main.java:14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is 013601267< enter>, `in.nextInt()` will take 013601267 as a single int because there are no space between digits. So you should call `in.nextInt()` one time and parse it into digits as you wanted.

Consider your input number begins with 0, you'd better use `in.nextLine()` to get it as a String instead of int, or the 0 at first position will be ignored.

You can do it like this:

```
while(in.hasNextLine) {
    String line = in.nextLine();
    int c1 = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(0,1));
    int c2 = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(1,2));
    //more lines here

}
```

Comment: thanx for your comment , but i am not allowed to use an Arraylist or array!

Comment: @Completely_new_to_java then you can write it line by line, as my newest update

Comment: It really helped me ! i have assignment on Monday! one finished 3 to go!

Comment: @Completely_new_to_java then you might click the accept button to accept my answer :)

Comment: haha. i am not just to new to java but i am also new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Completely_new_to_java :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting that when your routine runs that `in.nextInt()` will see a number like this:

013601267

and return 0 the first time it is called, 1 the second time, 3 the third time, etc.

When, in fact, the first time you call `in.nextInt()` it is actually returning the entire number 013601267.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Without seeing the stacktrace, that:

```
while (in.hasNextInt()) {
    int c1 = in.nextInt();
    int c2 = in.nextInt();
    int c3 = in.nextInt();
    int c4 = in.nextInt();
    int c5 = in.nextInt();
    int c6 = in.nextInt();
    int c7 = in.nextInt();
    int c8 = in.nextInt();
    int c9 = in.nextInt();
```

Is calling for that kind of exception. You have just checked one time if "in" hasNextInt, but you have called nextInt 9 times.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with Java learning, when you start understanding what you do, it even gets funny :-)